# Rest API mocking with wiremock : java

Tags: java, json, rest, api, wiremock

This is my utility class to mock the service

```
public class MockService {


    public static void bootUpMockServices() throws IOException {

        String orderServiceSpecification = readFile("mappings/orderServicesSpecifications.json", Charset.defaultCharset());
        String singleOrder = readFile("mappings/singleOrder.json", Charset.defaultCharset());


        WireMock.stubFor(WireMock.get(WireMock.urlEqualTo("/orders"))
                .willReturn(WireMock.aResponse()
                        .withStatus(200)
                        .withBody(orderServiceSpecification)));

        WireMock.stubFor(WireMock.get(WireMock.urlEqualTo("/orders/1"))
                .willReturn(WireMock.aResponse()
                        .withStatus(200)
                        .withBody(singleOrder)));

    }

    public static String readFile(String path, Charset encoding) 
            throws IOException {
        byte[] encoded = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path));
        return new String(encoded, encoding);
    }

}
```

As you can see I'm mocking a GET call `/orders` (with all the orders) and responding with the body with all the orders kept in a json file.

I'm also calling a single order by GET call `/orders/1`. I'm responding it with an JSON object in a file. But I want it to be dynamic. Like when I hit it with `orders/30` then, I should be dynamically fetch order with `id=30` and render it.

Comment: Could you add your json files' content?

Comment: @Areca. They are just files with JSON arrays. I don't see relevance with the content of them. why did u ask so?

Comment: If your singleOrder.json has only one item, how would you make it dynamic?

Comment: @Areca. Stubbing in wiremock has two ways, Java way (which is shown above) and using json files (mappings directory). Since I'm using Java way it doesn't matter what is there in the json file because I'm just converting to string and putting it in the response body. If you know how to stub the above problem in json file please tell me.:) thank you and correct me if I'm wrong. :)

Comment: How are you getting on with Tom's answer below, @RaghunandanJ?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, if you want dynamic behaviour of the kind you described you'll need to write a ResponseDefinitionTransformer and register it with the WireMockServer or WireMockRule on construction.

This is documented here: http://wiremock.org/docs/extending-wiremock/#transforming-responses

Example of a transformer implementation here:
https://github.com/tomakehurst/wiremock/blob/master/src/test/java/com/github/tomakehurst/wiremock/ResponseDefinitionTransformerAcceptanceTest.java#L208-L222

What you're trying to do could be done pretty straightforwardly with a stub mapping matching on a URL regex something like `/orders/(\d+)` and a transformer that parses out the number part then modifies the `bodyFileName` on the `ResponseDefinition`.